# python numpy array reduction distance between elements

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, flatten

I have an array in python made like this:

```
array([     18,      36,      54, ..., 9893804, 9893822, 9893840],
      dtype=int64)
```

I wish to obtain an array containing the "distances" bewteen ech byte...

in this case it would be:
[18,18,18, ..., xxx, 18, 18]

to do that I use an ugly `for i in range(len(arr))`

I suspect there is a way by using np.flatnonzero(something)
I could not find it..
any clue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about `np.diff(arr)`?

```
arr = np.array(...)
print(np.diff(arr)) # [18 18 18 ... 18 18 18]
```

Comment: very nice! but I have a problem: if an element is >256 it must become 4 elements so that the first is 00 and the other 3 are the number in little endian...

Comment: so I can do: np.argwhere(data > 255)  to get the indices ... obviously I could insert the required data in a for loop but I am learning numpy.. and I don't know how to do it with numpy internals

Comment: @Zibri I'm not sure what is the issue, can you please give an example and the expected output?

Comment: @i have to create an array with the distances. like you did. but if the distance is >255 I have to write 00 XX XX XX   where XXXXX is the distance in little endian.

Comment: so if I do: `z=np.argwhere(data > 255)
np.where(data<256,data,data*4096)
`
I get an array with the distance*4096 but as a single element I need 4

Comment: what I need is this: any idea? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69269305/how-to-do-a-rising-edge-detection-on-a-numpy-array-and-get-also-the-distances